# Node.js API - Select where like for multiple values in comma seperated string

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have this api (with node.js and mysql):

```
localhost:4001/api/?id=555,666
localhost:4001/api/?id=555
```

In the select I'm checking if the parameter has a comma (',') like this:

```
...
if (id.includes(",")) {     
    return `${field} IN (?);` 
} else {
    return `${field} = ?`
} 
...
```

... to get such a result:

```
SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (555,666)"
SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=555;"
```

It works great if I filter for fix values. But what about LIKE filtering?

E.g. if I filter for multiple names I do this:

```
localhost:4001/api/?name=money,invest,stocks
localhost:4001/api/?name=money,invest
localhost:4001/api/?name=money

...
if (name.includes(",")) {       
    return `${field} IN (?)` 
} else {
    return `${field} LIKE ?`
} 
...

Result:

SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (money,invest,stocks)"  
SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (money,invest)"
SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE money;"
```

... but what I would like to have is this:

```
Goal:

SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%money%' OR name LIKE '%invest%' OR name LIKE '%stocks%';"   
SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%money%' OR name LIKE '%invest%';"
SQL: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE money;"
```

How to I need to alter my query?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are going for but does this help? Select * from your_table where 'name' like '%money,%' or name like '%invest,%';

Comment: Yes ... but how do I need to alter this part: return `${field} IN (?)`  ? I guess I somehow need to split(',') the input and loop over the values and return it ... but how

Comment: Yes, that is why I said I am not 100% on what you are going for.  Lets say you are looking for "money," OR "invest,".  Can the table be stored like "money, value1, invest"  OR "money, invest" OR "invest,money" OR "money, value1, invest, value2"?  See what I mean?

Comment: BTW php version of "split" is "explode"

Comment: I would like to get this: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%money%' OR name LIKE '%invest%';" when input is localhost:4001/api/?name=money,invest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example, but read considerations about SQL Injection below:

```js
var name = "money,invest,stocks";

var str = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";

if (name.includes(",")) {  
  var names = name.split(",");
  names.map((o,i)=>{
    str += "name LIKE '%"+o+"%' ";
   (i==names.length -1)?str += "":str += "OR ";

  }) 
} else{
  str += "name LIKE '%"+name+"%' ";
}

console.log(str);
```

You could use `.split()` to transform the string to array, and `.map()` to iterate the new array.

---

I don't know wich driver are you using, but if you paste the query just like above example **your code is exposed to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)**, to [prevent this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), you should use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). So if you are using **mysql** library in nodejs the example would be somethig like:

```
var name = "money,invest,stocks";

var str = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";

if (name.includes(",")) {  
  var names = name.split(",");
  names.map((o,i)=>{
    names[i] = '%'+o+'%'; 
    str += "name LIKE ? ";
   (i==names.length -1)?str += "":str += "OR ";

  }) 
} else{
  str += "name LIKE ? ";
}

console.log(str);//SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?
console.log(names);//[ '%money%', '%invest%', '%stocks%' ]
```

And in the query, you should pass all parameters as array (names in this case) like this:

```
connection.query(str,names,function(err,rows){
    //connection.release();
    if(!err) {
      //further code
      }
    });
```

Comment: @PhilippM , I've updated the answer with some considerations about SQL Injection